# How do I represent a recursive process down a tree in a sequence diagramm?

Tags: uml, recursion, trees, sequence-diagram

I'm working on a sequence diagram for a layered system that has a tree hierarchy. Now I have a process that works itself recursively down the tree. Meaning calling the same function on a child object.

I'm talking about a tree like this:

```
-layer n
   -layer n-1
       -layer n-2
           -...
       -layer n-2
           -...
   -layer n-1
       -layer n-2
           -...
       -layer n-2
           -...
```

Its easy to visualize a recursive process in the single object, but I could figure out how I would visualize recursive process that recursively calls itself on a lower layer object and so on. Is this even possible with an UML sequence diagram?

Comment: Search Recursive on this link...https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28445/UML-Interview-Questions-Part

Comment: I'm afraid this page only shows how to do a recursion on the same object.

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325600/what-is-the-best-uml-diagram-for-explaining-recursive-tree-traversal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [sequence diagram](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html) doesn't represent a process, but a sequence of interaction between objects, where an object is a specific instance of a class.

Therefore, the representation of the recursion would be similar to the way you represent it in code:  in one diagram you would only show what happen at one level of your recursion:

[image]

If there is no other object involved in the recursion, you would use a [self-message](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/self_message.html).

Comment: Why are the execution specifications shifted to the right (left:node and right:node)? Is this a bug in the diagram or part of the notion of recursion?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator No, this is a bug in the diagram. Perhaps related to the way I copied and resized it.